# Redirect TCP data to ttyS0

Tags: linux, serial-port, socat

I have a closed application running on a different, but network accessible, Linux OS that is using [SerialIO](https://serialio.com/products/applications/custom-prior-software-versions/java-serial-port) to open /dev/ttyS0.

How can I write to ttyS0 from a different device so that the existing application will see what I'm writing as actual serial data?

Ive tried quite a few different *socat* commands and havent had luck.

```
socat -d -d /dev/ttyS0,raw,echo=0,b9600 tcp-l:6174,reuseaddr
socat -d -d pty,link=/dev/ttyS0,raw,echo=0 tcp-l:6174,reuseaddr
```

Any ideas on what is the best way to do this so that the existing (untouchable) application will think nothing has happened?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the ser2net daemon.  It is able to act as a TCP serial server for either raw or RFC2217 connections.

Comment: Looking at it now, seems promising. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll let you know how it works out.

Comment: I'm not having any luck with it. If I do "cat -vet /dev/ttyS0," should I see anything coming across?

My ser2net.conf file contains one line
    "6177:raw:0:/dev/ttyS0:9600 8DATABITS NONE 1STOPBIT"